# object doesn't support this property or method Issue with IE 8

Tags: jquery

Hi good people of the web, i have an issue with the script below.

I keep on getting an `object doesn't support this property or method` issue on the method `.length`. Any ideas ?

Thx 
Jay

```
$('input:hidden').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if($("[name='"+name+"']").length >1){
        if($(this).attr('type')!=='radio' && $(this).attr('type')!=='submit' 
                                          && $(this).attr('type')!=='button' 
                                          && $(this).attr('type')!=='text'
                                          && $(this).attr('type')!=='checkbox'
                                          && $(this).attr('type')!=='select'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How could an hidden input with a type that is not `hidden`?

Comment: The .length should work http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/cjvDG/
Could you post html too?

Comment: Please explain the reason for the code. If you are trying to remove all hidden fields, then why the test of the attr? As @xdazz said, you only have hidden fields inside the each.

Comment: Hi, lemme try to explain what i am trying to do : i have an html table with lots of  data, i want to be able to go forth and backwards with my form, theirfor i have next and previous buttons, i save my data from the table with jquery in a string. Now on previous click; i want to load the data previously slected by the user. My problem is the string containing the html have doubles, so i use the script to remove the doubles.

Comment: Works like a charm with FF it's only with IE that i have those issues

Comment: I am not trying to remove ALl the hidden fields, only the doubles.

Comment: You should restrict updating it once rather deleting those. Give a try with one method. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Since you have duplicates, how can you sure that which value is correct or let me know duplicated `value, name and id` is also the same

Comment: Hi Venkat, In fact after i click my previous button, for some reason jquery duplicates every thing in the string , duplicated values are the same, so it doesnt pose any problem on this side, i can delete either.

Comment: Hi Buddy, i don't know your name! Any way, Try my answer for your problem and let me know :)

Comment: I would call your issue a code smell and you need to fix your duplication instead of fixing the issue afterwards

Comment: Good @mplungjan: Thats correct. i already pointed out that! ;)

Comment: OK, thx guys.
Here is the complete proccess. I have a form with multiple pages, i navigate between those pages using jquery and i store the data in something i called $dataArray. On the click on next button all hidden data is stored in my $dataArray in the form of name="data". The problem occures when i click the previous button and then next again = > duplicates my data . This is why i want to delete duplicates after clicking previous. Hope this explains a bit. I am kinda new to all this and trying to learn to think around problems better.

Comment: are you talking about the .one ? , if yes at what time should i use it ?  when i append data to my string ?

Comment: Use the jQuery plugin or $("[name='" + name + "']").slice(1).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `size()` instead of `length`

```
$("[name='"+name+"']").size()
```

Comment: I did use size(), same issue.

Comment: Also i have another issue with this following function, i get a  Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

function loadPreviousPage(){
 document.getElementById('formHeader').scrollIntoView();

 razInfosErreur();
 $("body").trigger('Loading.Start');
 
 setTimeout(function() {
     // Call Operation Here
     try{
   var page = parseInt($("input#currentPage").val());
   var phpNextPage = page-1;
   loadPage(phpNextPage);
     }
     finally{
         $("body").trigger('Loading.End');
     }
 }, 50); 
  
}

Answer (score 0):

You really need to fix the underlying issue of duplication instead of hacking the resulting error.

That said: **ALTHOUGH** Internet explorer (8 at least) does not have a length attribute on a single input field, **jQuery 1.10 in IE8** will return 1 on both .length and .size() so you need to give us more information and show some html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test length</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $.each(["test1","test2"],function(i,name) {
      var input = $("input[name="+name+"]");
      var dotlength = input.length;
      var size = input.size();
      window.console && console.log("input.length:",dotlength);
      window.console && console.log("input.size():",size);  
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="test1" /><hr>
<input name="test2" /><br><input name="test2" /><br>
</body>
</html>
```

gives in IE:

```
LOG: input.length:1
LOG: input.size():1
LOG: input.length:2
LOG: input.size():2
```

Comment: `length` is a jQuery object property, so it shouldn't matter what the browser is.

Comment: `if(fields.length)` is enough instead of `if(fields.length && fields.length >1)`.

Comment: Yeah - if field.length !=null is what I actually meant

Comment: @Archer You are correct - I just tested it and it does indeed work in at least IE8 with jQuery 1.10

Comment: Hi again ,  mplungjan i tried to do it your way, same error albeit this time it's not the length that is causing the issue, for the debugger the issue is caused by this "var fields = $("[name="+name+"]");" now.

Answer (score 0):

Does not required to check those thing, Make a try with a below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:hidden').each(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      $("[name='" + name + "']").slice(1).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you are very new. you can use any below plugin for your multi form, so you can avoid `Browser compatibility issues` and make your code clean

http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/
http://wbotelhos.com/stepy
http://thecodemine.org/